# How to call a function from a class - error "was not in the scope"

Tags: c++

This is my program which leads to compilation errors mentioned below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class weight{
    private:
        float current_weight, diet_weight, num_exercise;
        int num_meal,i;

    public:

        // make users to enter current weight
        void get_curent_weight()
        {
            cout<<"Please enter your current weight: "; 
            cin>>current_weight;
        }
        void enter_data()
        {
            for (i=1; i>7; i++)
            {
                cout<<"Day "<<i<<endl;
                cout<<"--------------"<<endl;
                // Number of Meal(s)
                cout<<"Number of meal(s) you eat today: ";
                cin>>num_meal;
                cout<<endl;
                // Number of Exercise
                cout<<"Number of hour(s) you spent on exercises today: ";
                cin>>num_exercise;
                cout<<endl;
            }
        }
        // output the information
        void information()
        {
            // calculate the final weight
            diet_weight=current_weight+(0.5*num_meal)-(num_exercise/3)*0.5;
            cout<<"Your weight after 7 days diet: "<<diet_weight<<endl;
        }
};

int main(){

    get_curent_weight();
    enter_data();
    information();
    return(0);
}
```

I get the following compilation errors

```
error: 'get_curent_weight' was not declared in this scope
error: 'enter_data' was not declared in this scope
error: 'information' was not declared in this scope
```

It seems I call the function in wrong way.... 
Thank you for reading my question, as a beginner of C++, I appreciate it. :))

Comment: in main() you need to create an instance of your class..  Then you call the functions on that instance.  I think you want something like this:  int main(){  weight myWeight;  myWeight.enter_data(); myWeight.get_current_weight(); myWeight.information(); return(0);}  make sure to call enter_data before calling the other methods, or they'll have 0 values and not yet be initialized...

Comment: Not a badly structured question. Could be minimized a bit, but not a sprawling disasterpiece. Not going to upvote because it's not too hard to research a solution to this problem. It should be covered in the first few chapters of any programming text that isn't an outright fraud and in basic C++ tutorials online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class can be called a blueprint; it's functions can only be implemented on an object of the class that function belongs to. That function cannot be called as a standalone. To resolve your error, you need to declare an object in your main() function with the data type `weight` and then call the function with that created object. An example of such would be like:

```
weight object_name;

object_name.get_curent_weight();
object_name.enter_data();
object_name.information();
```

Alternatively, you can take the functions out of the class; this way, they can be used without an object of class `weight`. This will take a lot more effort over the first choice I suggested.

Comment: You're welcome. Please select the green check mark next to my answer. You can also upvote my answer if you liked it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of the class, and call the member functions on that instance:

```
int main() {
    weight my_weight;
    my_weight.get_curent_weight();
    my_weight.enter_data();
    my_weight.information();
    return 0;
}
```